# problem after excluding side bars from a wordpress page

Tags: wordpress

i have a problem after excluding side bars from a wordpress page here http://www.topfxrebates.com
 i want to fill the space of the removed side bars because i need to draw a big table that fits the whole page
here are some screenshots

1 - the problem 
http:// img2.pict.com/99/9d/c7/3799424/0/1279296576.jpg
2 - this is what i want to do
http:// img2.pict.com/b4/75/1b/3799423/0/1279296572.jpg

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Just put an ids on the body to differentiate between the pages with and without a sidebar. (I assume you are using display: none; or not including the sidebar and not using visibility: none;), if you are using the latter, then change it to display: none;

```
<body id="with_sidebar">
   <div class="content">
   </div>
   <div class="sidebar">
   </div>
</div>

#with_sidebar .content{width: 60%;)

<body id="without_sidebar">
   <div class="content">
   </div>
</div>

#without_sidebar .content{width: 100%;)
```

Just looked at your code, seems the easiest thing for you to do would be to change

```
<div id="content">
```

to

```
<div id="content" class="nosidebar">
```

Then add this to your CSS:

```
#content.nosidebar{width: 100%;}
```

Comment: yes here is the code of the page (no side bar) template 
topfxrebates.com/code.txt
here is the css file 
topfxrebates.com/wp-content/themes/Spades/style.css